# Javascript: difference between calling lambda function or just a direct expression?

Tags: javascript, function, lambda, expression

I sometimes see JS constructs like this:

```js
var foo = (function(){ return some_expression; })();
```

What can be the reason for this? Is this in any way different to the much simpler:

```
var foo = some_expression;
```

I happen to came across such an example [here](https://www.paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/) (the `window.requestAnimFrame = ...` code) but I've seen it in many others places.

I know one reason to wrap stuff in a lambda function is to keep variables local, but that doesn't apply in this particular example.

Comment: It's addressed in the comments: https://www.paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/#comment-918142887 The author had an error in the script, and thought that the IIFE solved it.

Comment: The IIFE doesn't make sense for that example. I don't see the point of it in the example in the page you linked to either - in the comments on that other page somebody asked the author about it and received a rather unsatisfactory answer.

Comment: I guess its just muscle memory :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that there seems to be any difference in your case but before ECMAScript 5, `undefined` was a property of the `window` object and was writable, so `undefined = "123"` would replace its value. This means that whenever any program below this line of code would try to check something like this-

```
var foo;
foo === undefined // false
```

one would get a wrong result.

In order to avoid this, a coding pattern like this was used -

```
(function(foo, bar, undefined) {
  // your code here
  // undefined here will always be the correct value (i.e., undefined === undefined) regardless of it being polluted somewhere outside this block
})(foo, bar)
```

But, this was pre ES5. So, it won't matter anymore